# Azure Data Factory Debugging Failure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I've been developing a pipeline in ADF with one simple copy activity taking data from SQL Server on premise up to an Azure SQL Database and yesterday came across an issue (pipeline image below)

[image]

My pipeline kept failing to debug in the same place with the same error

```
{
    "errorCode": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The integration runtime 'Integration-Runtime-Name' under data factory 'Data-Factory-Name' does not exist. ",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "PiplineActivity"
}
```

The day before it had worked without any issues, and I realised although the debug run failed, if I kicked off a trigger run the pipeline would succeed.

I tested this out with a couple of different runtime environments and a completely new pipeline, but got the same result. I even stripped the one copy task it was trying to do down to a simple test table with one column and one row.

Can anyone else verify they are seeing the same or different behavior? or point out if I'm doing anything wrong. I would like to emphasise it was working fine the day before yesterday.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. Please have a try again. Thanks.

Comment: Yes looks like the bug has been fixed